# Google Map not working since upgrade to Android Studio 2.1.2 on new laptop

Tags: android, android-studio, maps, upgrade

I recently transferred my project from one laptop to another.
I installed the latest version of Android Studio, which is 2.1.2
My old laptop was running version 1.5.1

After importing the `gradle.build` into the new version on the new laptop, my `MapsActivity` is no longer working, whereas it worked perfectly before.
As such, I know the problem is not in the code, or the API key from google.

I think I have got all the same packages downloaded from the SDK manager.

When it was initially "rebuilt", it suggested there was a fragment "issue" which I resolved by downloading the Google Play Services, but now it shows nothing at all.

Any help or advice very welcome.
The following message appears when I run the app in the AVD emulator.

```
06-09 18:43:17.909 2971-2971/com.example.grant.fbcc I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
06-09 18:43:18.016 2971-2971/com.example.grant.fbcc W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.grant.fbcc-1/lib/x86
06-09 18:43:28.469 2971-2971/com.example.grant.fbcc W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.grant.fbcc-1/lib/x86
06-09 18:43:28.597 2971-2971/com.example.grant.fbcc W/art: Verification of void com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.<init>(com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzaa) took 101.927ms
06-09 18:43:28.679 2971-2971/com.example.grant.fbcc I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
06-09 18:43:28.679 2971-2971/com.example.grant.fbcc I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
06-09 18:43:28.717 2971-2971/com.example.grant.fbcc E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
06-09 18:43:28.717 2971-2971/com.example.grant.fbcc E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
06-09 18:43:28.782 2971-3094/com.example.grant.fbcc E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
06-09 18:43:29.031 2971-2971/com.example.grant.fbcc W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-09 18:43:29.162 2971-3105/com.example.grant.fbcc D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

                                                                  [ 06-09 18:43:29.168  2971: 2971 D/         ]
                                                                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa15a2330, tid 2971


                                                                  [ 06-09 18:43:29.211  2971: 3105 D/         ]
                                                                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa15a20f0, tid 3105
06-09 18:43:29.219 2971-3105/com.example.grant.fbcc I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-09 18:43:39.145 2971-3094/com.example.grant.fbcc I/GMPM: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
06-09 18:45:48.613 2971-2977/com.example.grant.fbcc W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.378ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you update your credentials in the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)?
If you're building on a new laptop, it has a different debug key, which won't work with the existing API key you have.

Go to the Developer Console > Credentials, create a new Android key with the updated SHA-1, and you should be back in business. (The DevCon site has instructions on how to get the SHA-1 off your new laptop if you need)

Comment: That worked a treat, very much appreciated. Never for a second did I think that the new build would require a new API key / SHA-1.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, which was definitely required for the original problem, I would like to add the following requirement that I found was required in my re-build: -

In the following link, are a number of compile statements,
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Of which I needed to add the following line to the app build gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
```